# Are there guidelines for the type area of a thesis?

Tags: formatting, typography

I am writing my bachelor thesis right know and i used a template from one of our lecturers and for me the type area seems kind of odd. This is the documentclass which is used in this template:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,DIV=8,BCOR=5mm,twoside,pdftex,bibtotocnumbered]{scrreprt}
```

Until now I always had left/right margins around 2-3cm and top/bottom margins also like 2-3cm but I also always done it the way which "looks" the best to me. But with this template the type area is much smaller and the margins are way way bigger. I don't know if this should be like that but I would trust a lecturer that he has made this intentionally. What would you recommend ? Maybe some other format or is this ok?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To address your question: I blame Microsoft Word for the “bad habit” of “2-3cm margins” (well, the default margins are 1in, or 2.54cm). Your university should have a general guideline for how much margins you should leave for binding. For example, mine requests that there should be at least 1.5in on the left-hand edge of the paper and at least 1in on the other three sides (note that it says “at least”, not “must be”).

Comment: Welcome! I would recommend checking with your lecturer, however it is very common for universities to require specific margins particularly if you need binding etc. Anyway, I don't think anyone here will be able to tell you what your university wants so you might want to check with them or check some of their previous dissertations handed by students.

Comment: DIV=8 (which sets the margins implicitly) is *much* better than the usual 2-3cm margins and typographically speaking a good choice.

Comment: BTW, after you find out about margin requirements, here is what I recommend: For text area width, use an integer multiple of the point size for body text. For example, letter papers with 8.5in width will have a text area 6in (8.5-1.5-1) wide, or less. This is 6*72.27=433.62pt. So `10pt` report can be `430pt` (or `420pt`, etc.) wide; `11pt` report can be `427.05pt` (or `416.1pt`, etc., n*10.95pt) wide; `12pt` report can be `432pt` (or `420pt`, etc., n*12pt) wide.

Comment: …and finally, for text area height, use `p+(n-1)*b`, where `p` is the point size for body text, `n` is the number of lines you want in a single page, and `b` is the baseline distance between two lines (also known as *leading*). The value of `b` depends on whether your university asks for “1.5-line spacing” or something like that. Make sure that `p+(n-1)*b` stays below the margin limits.

Comment: For a good text block size you want to have roughly 60-70 characters per line (a bit more if you're using 1.5 spacing), with DIV=8 you get around 66 characters per line, which is pretty good.

Comment: My *A Few Notes on Book Design* (`> texdoc memdesign`) shows some 36 page layout designs. It also includes a dozen example title page designs.